# Greater than operator jquery not returning true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a greater than operation with Jquery but there is something I am missing. If the greater than operation returns `true` an `alert()` is supposed to be thrown, but it doesn't.

How am I supposed to wrap these variables so that it is recognized as numbers? Or whatever else I am supposed to do.

See code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_new_log").click(function(event) {

    var current_total= $("#current_total").val();
    var total_waste_processed = $("#total_waste_processed").val();

    if (current_total > total_waste_processed) {
      alert("value surpassed");
    }

  });
});
```

See fiddle:
[JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nicholas116/8o7sh2j7/16/)

Comment: Where do you even define the variables you're comparing?

Comment: You're setting `waste_id` twice.  Where do you set `current_total` and `total_waste_processed`?

Comment: my error. @RocketHazmat

Comment: @david as I mentioned previously, the question had an error in it, alongside the fiddle. but as you recognized correctly, i was looking for the parseInt() function. thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all you're not actually defining the variables that you're comparing.  Perhaps you *meant to* here?:

```
var current_total = $("#current_total").val();
var total_waste_processed = $("#total_waste_processed").val();
```

This would define them as the strings from those inputs.  If those inputs are only going to produce numbers and you want them handled as numbers, you'd have to parse them as such.  For example, if they're integers:

```
var current_total = parseInt($("#current_total").val());
var total_waste_processed = parseInt($("#total_waste_processed").val());
```

That way the comparison would be as numbers, rather than as strings.  (Since, with strings, things like `"100"` are "smaller than", say, `"5"`.)

Comment: THIS is what i meant to do, there was an error in my fiddle

Answer (score 3):

Use `parseInt()` to get the number.

Also there are a few things wrong in your code:

You have 2x `waste_id` and you use two unknown variables `current_total` and `total_waste_processed`

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8o7sh2j7/13/

Comment: As i would of mentioned previously, the 2x waste_id was an error

Answer (score 1):

You should parse your variables `current_total` & `total_waste_processed` to int using **[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** since `.val()` return string, so if you want to use mathematical operators like `>` you should parse those string to integers, your code should be like following example.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_new_log").click(function(event) {

    var current_total = parseInt($("#current_total").val());
    var total_waste_processed = parseInt($("#total_waste_processed").val());

    if (current_total > total_waste_processed) {
        alert("value surpassed");
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='current_total' placeholder='current total'/>
<input type='text' id='total_waste_processed' placeholder='total waste processed'/>

<button id='add_new_log'>Add new log</button>
```